# Get the actual Previous Fire Time of a CronTrigger / Scheduled Apex

Tags: scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, asynchronous, cron

I am exeuting Scheduled Apex that should do processing based on the last execution time of the particular code. I query some records for processing and I only want to query those records, that have been changed (SystemModStamp) since the last time the code executed. So I am looking for something lile this:

```sql
SELECT ... FROM sObject WHERE SystemModStamp >= :LastExecution
```

Where LastExecution is automatically calculated during the exceution. If I have code that does not execute within the Cron (say, in Anonymous Apex), this is relatively easy to accomplish:

```java
DateTime LastExecution = DateTime.valueOf([SELECT MAX(PreviousFireTime)LastRun FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name LIKE :cronName][0].get('LastRun')
```

or even easier, if I know the CronTrigger Id:

```java
DateTime LastExecution = [SELECT PreviousFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :arbitraryId].PreviousFireTime
```

Unfortunately, this pattern does not work if the latter unit is executed from within the scheduled context (thus, retrieving the Trigger id from `SchedulableContext.getTriggerId()`). Salesforce updates the CronTrigger record before the code is executed. PreviousFireTime is always the time of execution.
[image]

I also tried quering the `AsyncApexJob`, but for standard recurring CronTriggers that are scheduled once, there is only **one** corresponding record in the queue that never gets 'Completed' but always stays 'Queued'. They also do not get re-created, so AsyncApexJob.CreatedDate is identical to CronTrigger.StartTime.

So my question: How do I get the "before" value of `PreviousFireTime`?
For relatively easy CronExpressions that define recurring triggers (say `0 0 * * * ?` or `0 0 0 * * ?`) I could calculate the difference between `PreviousFireTime` and `NextFireTime` and simply substract this difference from `PreviousFireTime` to "calculate" an actual previous time. However, this fails for any more complex CronExpressions (say a Job that executes once every hour during business hours (from 8 AM to 8 PM) and if I try to calculate this on the first and last run).

Comment: Have you tried saving previous CronTrigger Ids and querying them after more than one job has run?  For sure it's not ideal, but you could create your own CronTrigger_Log__c custom object and in the `finish()` method (or even `start()`), create a new log record with an Id to the previous run, as well as run times.

Comment: Implementing a custom log functionality would be my last resort. I have a logging / disagnostics package in place which I could utilize. But I prefer native platform functionalities ober custom "hacks" (because ihey always introduce new dependencies, which I prefer to avoid).

Comment: I hear - I just don't think the current running job has any knowledge or access to the previous runtime :-/

Answer (score 1):

I decided to implement a CronHandler that can be constructed from either a cron id, a scheduled job name or a list of configs that allows me to calculate a Last Execution Time based on a couple of premises.

- For inits with a trigger id (i.e. from SchedulableContext), only one CronTrigger  record is initialized
- For inits with a list of CronTrigger records or a Job Name (best used with wildcards), all matching records are initialized

The API `DateTime getLastExection()` iterates all configs in the handler and returns the **latest** DateTime value there is. A cron config object can handle the following states:

1. EXECUTING and no recognized pattern for a recurring job: Returns null
2. EXEUCTING and recognized pattern for a recurring job: Returns a calculated previous fire Time based on distance to the next fire time (with a small 10% overlap)
3. NOT EXECUTING (i.e. WAITING, etc): Returns the PreviousFireTime from CronTrigger object. May be null, if the trigger never ran.

This is enough to:

- Evaluate an actual previous fire time directly from SOQL for a series of crons, as long as I have a similar naming schema ('Job #1', 'Job #2', etc). Does not require the crons to be scheduled symmetrical (e.g. 0,15,30,45)
- Estimate the last fire time for a single cron as long as the cron is scheduled to run regularily ('0 0 * * * ?', ...). This works for hourly and daily scheduled jobs equally.

I would be happy to hear your feedback and suggestions to improve the code.

Here's the class:

```java
 public class CronHandler {

    @testVisible private List<CronConfiguration> CronConfigs;

    public CronHandler(Id cronTriggerId) {
        this([SELECT Id,StartTime,EndTime,PreviousFireTime,NextFireTime,TimesTriggered,CronExpression,State,CronJobDetail.Name FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :cronTriggerId]);
    }

    public CronHandler(String jobName) {
        this([SELECT Id,StartTime,EndTime,PreviousFireTime,NextFireTime,TimesTriggered,CronExpression,State,CronJobDetail.Name FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name LIKE :jobName]);
    }

    public CronHandler(List<CronTrigger> triggerConfigs) {
        CronConfigs = new List<CronHandler.CronConfiguration>();
        for (CronTrigger ct : triggerConfigs) CronConfigs.add(new CronConfiguration(ct));
    }

    // DESCRIPTION
    //      simply forwards the size of all internal configs that are known
    public Integer getCronConfigSize() {
        return CronConfigs.size();
    }

    // DESCRIPTION
    //      Returns the highest value for previous fire time for all configs that are known to the handler
    //      The configs itself dynamically evaluate if they are to a executing or a waiting cron job
    //      And return their actual previous fire time or a calculated estimator
    // RETURN
    //      DateTime: The highest previous fire time of all configs
    public DateTime getLastExecution() {
        List<DateTime> ExecutionDateTimes = new List<DateTime>();
        for (CronHandler.CronConfiguration cc : CronConfigs) ExecutionDateTimes.add(cc.getPreviousFireTime());
        ExecutionDateTimes.sort();
        return ExecutionDateTimes.isEmpty() ? null : ExecutionDateTimes.get(ExecutionDateTimes.size() - 1);
    }

    public class CronConfiguration {

        public String CronExpression;
        public String State;
        public String CronDetailName;
        public DateTime PreviousFireTime;
        public DateTime NextFireTime;
        public Integer TimesTriggered;

        // blank constructor to emulate a cron config for testing
        public CronConfiguration() { }

        // load configuration from a CronTrigger record
        public CronConfiguration(CronTrigger ct) {
            CronExpression = ct.CronExpression;
            State = ct.State;
            CronDetailName = ct.CronJobDetail.Name;
            PreviousFireTime = ct.PreviousFireTime;
            NextFireTime = ct.NextFireTime;
            TimesTriggered = ct.TimesTriggered;
        }

        // DESCRIPTION
        //      Returns the best estimator for this CronJob's last execution. If trigger is not executing, returns the actual PreviousFireTime.
        //      Otherwise, calculates the estimated previous fire time based on cron expression and next fire time.
        // RETURN
        //      DateTime: Best guessed previous fire time for the cron config
        public DateTime getPreviousFireTime() {
            if (State != 'EXECUTING') return PreviousFireTime;
            if (matchesRecurringJobExpression(CronExpression)) return DateTime.newInstance(PreviousFireTime.getTime() - getTimeDifference(NextFireTime, PreviousFireTime));
            return null;
        }

        // DESCRIPTION
        //      Calculates the difference in milliseconds between two dateTimes.
        //      The difference is then multiplied by 10%, to account for inaccuracies
        // PARAMETERS
        //      DateTime dtNext: expected to be the higher of both values
        //      DateTime dtPrev: expected to be the lower of both values
        // RETURN
        //      Long: Difference between both datetime values with 10% inaccuracy
        private Long getTimeDifference(DateTime dtNext, DateTime dtPrev) {
            return ((dtNext.getTime() - dtPrev.getTime())*1.1).longValue();
        }

        // DESCRIPTION
        //      Splits the cron expression in its part and validates each list-element individually
        //      Only validates elements where wildards may appear (hour and up) and exists with false
        // RETURN
        //      Boolean: Evaluation, if expression represents a regular recurring job
        private Boolean matchesRecurringJobExpression(String cronExp) {
            List<String> splitExpression = cronExp.split(' ');
            // hours (3rd element): fix numbers or recurring is accepted
            if (!Pattern.matches('[0-9]{1,2}|\\*', splitExpression.get(2))) return false;
            // days of month (4th element): only recurring / arbitrary is accepted
            if (!Pattern.matches('\\*|\\?', splitExpression.get(3))) return false;
            // month (5th element): only recurring is accepted
            if (!Pattern.matches('\\*', splitExpression.get(4))) return false;
            // day of week (6th element): only recurring / arbitrary is accepted
            if (!Pattern.matches('\\*|\\?', splitExpression.get(5))) return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And here are some tests:

```java
@isTest
public class T_CronHandler {

    @isTest
    static void initHandlerByName_NoCronConfigurationsExisting_NoConfigsLoaded() {
        CronHandler ch = new CronHandler('Unknown Test Config');
        System.assertEquals(0, ch.getCronConfigSize(), 'Configs have been initiated, but expecting 0');
    }

    @isTest
    static void initHandlerById_NoCronConfigurationsExisting_NoConfigsLoaded() {
        // SETUP
        // this is a syntactically valid cron trigger id that should never exist 
        Id invalidId = '08e4E00000XXXXXXXX';
        CronHandler ch = new CronHandler(invalidId);
        // VERIFY
        System.assertEquals(0, ch.getCronConfigSize(), 'Configs have been initiated, but expecting 0');        
    }

    @isTest
    static void initHandlerByName_SingleCronConfigurationExisting_OneConfigLoaded() {
        // SETUP
        // schedule the Dispatcher_ScheduledSends
        System.schedule('Test Send #1', '0 0 * * * ?', new Dispatcher_ScheduledSends());
        CronHandler ch = new CronHandler('Test Send%');
        // VERIFY
        System.assertEquals(1, ch.getCronConfigSize(), 'Wrong number of cron configs initiated');
    }

    @isTest
    static void initHandlerByName_MultipleCronConfigurationExisting_AllConfigsLoaded() {
        // SETUP
        // schedule the Dispatcher_ScheduledSends
        System.schedule('Test Send #1', '0 0 * * * ?', new Dispatcher_ScheduledSends());
        System.schedule('Test Send #3', '0 15 * * * ?', new Dispatcher_ScheduledSends());
        System.schedule('Test Send #2', '0 30 * * * ?', new Dispatcher_ScheduledSends());
        System.schedule('Test Send #4', '0 45 * * * ?', new Dispatcher_ScheduledSends());
        CronHandler ch = new CronHandler('Test Send%');
        // VERIFY
        System.assertEquals(4, ch.getCronConfigSize(), 'Wrong number of cron configs initiated');
    }

    @isTest
    static void initHandlerByName_MultipleCronConfigurationOnDifferentNamesExisting_OnlyMatchingConfigsLoaded() {
        // SETUP
        // schedule the Dispatcher_ScheduledSends
        System.schedule('First Send #1', '0 0 * * * ?', new Dispatcher_ScheduledSends());
        System.schedule('First Send #3', '0 15 * * * ?', new Dispatcher_ScheduledSends());
        System.schedule('Another Send #1', '0 30 * * * ?', new Dispatcher_ScheduledSends());
        System.schedule('Another Send #2', '0 45 * * * ?', new Dispatcher_ScheduledSends());
        CronHandler ch = new CronHandler('First Send%');
        // VERIFY
        System.assertEquals(2, ch.getCronConfigSize(), 'Wrong number of cron configs initiated');
    }

    @isTest
    static void getLastExecution_NoConfigLoaded_Null() {
        CronHandler ch = new CronHandler('Unknown Test Config');
        System.assertEquals(null, ch.getLastExecution(), 'Wrong value for last execution');
    }

    @isTest
    static void getLastExecution_ExecutingCronInitialized_PrevFromExecuting() {
        CronHandler ch = new CronHandler('Unknown Test Config');
        // ACTION
        CronHandler.CronConfiguration cc = new CronHandler.CronConfiguration();
        cc.State = 'EXECUTING';
        cc.CronExpression = '0 0 * * * ?';
        cc.PreviousFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 07, 23, 57);
        cc.NextFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 08, 23, 55);
        ch.CronConfigs.add(cc);
        // VERIFY
        System.assertNotEquals(null, ch.getLastExecution(), 'Last execution is null');
        System.assertEquals(cc.getPreviousFireTime(), ch.getLastExecution(), 'Wrong value for last execution');
    }

    @isTest
    static void getLastExecution_MultipleHourlyCrons_WaitingHasExecutions_PrevFromWaiting() {
        CronHandler ch = new CronHandler('Unknown Test Config');
        // ACTION
        // setup config for executing job
        CronHandler.CronConfiguration cc1 = new CronHandler.CronConfiguration();
        cc1.State = 'EXECUTING';
        cc1.CronExpression = '0 0 * * * ?';
        cc1.PreviousFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 07, 00, 2);
        cc1.NextFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 08, 00, 00);
        ch.CronConfigs.add(cc1);
        // setup config for waiting job
        CronHandler.CronConfiguration cc2 = new CronHandler.CronConfiguration();
        cc2.State = 'WAITING';
        cc2.CronExpression = '0 30 * * * ?';
        cc2.PreviousFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 06, 30, 05);
        cc2.NextFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 07, 30, 00);
        ch.CronConfigs.add(cc2);
        // VERIFY
        System.assertNotEquals(null, ch.getLastExecution(), 'Last execution is null');
        System.assertEquals(cc2.getPreviousFireTime(), ch.getLastExecution(), 'Wrong value for last execution');
    }

    @isTest
    static void getLastExecution_MixedHourlyAndDailyCrons_WaitingHasExecutions_PrevFromWaiting() {
        CronHandler ch = new CronHandler('Unknown Test Config');
        // ACTION
        // setup config for executing job
        CronHandler.CronConfiguration cc1 = new CronHandler.CronConfiguration();
        cc1.State = 'EXECUTING';
        cc1.CronExpression = '0 0 * * * ?';
        cc1.PreviousFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 07, 00, 2);
        cc1.NextFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 08, 00, 00);
        ch.CronConfigs.add(cc1);
        // setup config for waiting job
        CronHandler.CronConfiguration cc2 = new CronHandler.CronConfiguration();
        cc2.State = 'WAITING';
        cc2.CronExpression = '0 30 23 * * ?';
        cc2.PreviousFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 05, 23, 30, 05);
        cc2.NextFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 23, 30, 00);
        ch.CronConfigs.add(cc2);
        // VERIFY
        System.assertNotEquals(null, ch.getLastExecution(), 'Last execution is null');
        System.assertEquals(cc1.getPreviousFireTime(), ch.getLastExecution(), 'Wrong value for last execution');
    }

    @isTest
    static void getLastExecution_WaitingHourlyCrons_NoExecutions_Null() {
        CronHandler ch = new CronHandler('Unknown Test Config');
        // ACTION
        // setup config for executing job
        CronHandler.CronConfiguration cc1 = new CronHandler.CronConfiguration();
        cc1.State = 'WAITING';
        cc1.CronExpression = '0 0 * * * ?';
        cc1.NextFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 07, 00, 00, 00);
        ch.CronConfigs.add(cc1);
        // setup config for waiting job
        CronHandler.CronConfiguration cc2 = new CronHandler.CronConfiguration();
        cc2.State = 'WAITING';
        cc2.CronExpression = '0 30 * * * ?';
        cc2.NextFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 07, 0, 30, 00);
        ch.CronConfigs.add(cc2);
        // VERIFY
        System.assertEquals(null, ch.getLastExecution(), 'Last execution is null');
    }

    @isTest
    static void cronConfig_getPreviousFireTime_NotExecuting_InternalValueReturned() {
        // SETUP
        // emulate a cron config for a waiting trigger
        CronHandler.CronConfiguration cc = new CronHandler.CronConfiguration();
        cc.PreviousFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 07, 23, 57);
        cc.NextFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 08, 23, 55);
        // ACTION & VERIFY
        cc.State = 'WAITING';
        System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 07, 23, 57), cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong previous fire time returned for WAITING');
        cc.State = 'PAUSED';
        System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 07, 23, 57), cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong previous fire time returned for PAUSED');
        cc.State = 'ACQUIRED';
        System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 07, 23, 57), cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong previous fire time returned for ACQUIRED');
        cc.State = 'COMPLETE';
        System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 07, 23, 57), cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong previous fire time returned for COMPLETED');
        cc.State = 'ERROR';
        System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 07, 23, 57), cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong previous fire time returned for ERROR');
        cc.State = 'BLOCKED';
        System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 07, 23, 57), cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong previous fire time returned for BLOCKED');
        cc.State = 'PAUSED_BLOCKED';
        System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 07, 23, 57), cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong previous fire time returned for PAUSED_BLOCKED');
    }

    @isTest
    static void cronConfig_getPreviousFireTime_NotExecutingNoRuns_RecurringCronExpression_InternalValueReturned() {
        // SETUP
        // emulate a cron config for a waiting trigger
        CronHandler.CronConfiguration cc = new CronHandler.CronConfiguration();
        cc.State = 'WAITING';
        cc.CronExpression = '0 30 * * * ?';
        cc.NextFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 08, 30, 00);
        // ACTION & VERIFY
        System.assertEquals(null, cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong value for WAITING');
    }

    @isTest
    static void cronConfig_getPreviousFireTime_Executing_RecurringCronExpression_CalculatedPrevTime() {
        // SETUP
        // emulate a cron config for a waiting trigger
        CronHandler.CronConfiguration cc = new CronHandler.CronConfiguration();
        cc.State = 'EXECUTING';
        cc.PreviousFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 07, 23, 57);
        cc.NextFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 08, 23, 55);
        // ACTION & VERIFY
        // calculate a DateTime with 10% bonus in difference
        DateTime expectedVal = DateTime.newInstance(cc.PreviousFireTime.getTime() - ((cc.NextFireTime.getTime() - cc.PreviousFireTime.getTime())*1.1).longValue());
        cc.CronExpression = '0 0 * * * ?';
        System.assertEquals(expectedVal, cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong value for: 0 0 * * * ?');
        cc.CronExpression = '0 0 * * * *';
        System.assertEquals(expectedVal, cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong value for: 0 0 * * * *');
        cc.CronExpression = '12 33 * * * ?';
        System.assertEquals(expectedVal, cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong value for: 12 33 * * * ?');
        cc.CronExpression = '0 0 5 * * ?';
        System.assertEquals(expectedVal, cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong value for: 0 0 5 * * ?');
        cc.CronExpression = '59 59 23 ? * * *';
        System.assertEquals(expectedVal, cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong value for: 59 59 23 ? * *');
    }

    @isTest
    static void cronConfig_getPreviousFireTime_Executing_NonrecurringCronExpression_Null() {
        // SETUP
        // emulate a cron config for a waiting trigger
        CronHandler.CronConfiguration cc = new CronHandler.CronConfiguration();
        cc.State = 'EXECUTING';
        cc.PreviousFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 07, 23, 57);
        cc.NextFireTime = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 05, 06, 08, 23, 55);
        // ACTION & VERIFY
        cc.CronExpression = '0 0 * 1/5 * ?';
        System.assertEquals(null, cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong value for: 0 0 * 1/5 * ?');
        cc.CronExpression = '12 33 22 ? * MON-FRI';
        System.assertEquals(null, cc.getPreviousFireTime(), 'Wrong value for: 12 33 22 ? * MON-FRI');

    }
}
```

Comment: cool; why all the instance vbls in `CronConfiguration`? why not a simple instance vbl of type `CronTrigger`?

Comment: So I can directly access (set/get) the instance-variables in tests. CronTrigger has a few crucial read-only properties, and since its a system-table that also has SeeAllDate=true enabled, testing the Config with actual CronTrigger-records only (without the ability to directly set the variables) would be tedious.

Comment: You can use JSON deserialize to set mock values into CronTriggrer regardless of read only attributes